# Different URL config depending on domain in Django

Tags: django, mezzanine

In Mezzanine there are two different URLs that you could use depending what content you want to be displayed. Is there a way to check **inside** the urls.py if the active domain is on a subdomain or just the "regular" domain?

**This is the two different styles:**

```
url('^$', direct_to_template, {'template': 'index.html'}, name='home'),
url('^$', mezzanine.blog.views.blog_post_list, name='home'),
```

I haven't found a solid way for this yet. I want to display blog_post_list if I am on a subdomain (wildcard / e.g. sub.example.com) and index.html if I am on the "main" domain (e.g. example.com)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the `urls.py` is loaded when your app boots up and only looks at the path. The current URL is part of the `request` objects, that the Middleware and the View receives.

However, you could use a view to delegate the request, based on the URL path.

```
url('^$', my_view, name='home')
```

And the view could use the current `request` object to delegate to one of the two subsequent views.

```
def my_view(request):
    if 'something' in request.META['HTTP_HOST']:
        return something_view(request)
    else:
        return another_view(request)
```

However, there is an app to do what you want to do, [django-hosts](https://django-hosts.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). It allows to load different `urls.py` files based on the host.

```
from django_hosts import patterns, host

host_patterns = patterns('path.to',
    host(r'api', 'api.urls', name='api'),
    host(r'beta', 'beta.urls', name='beta'),
)
```